# How to set the Fill property of a combobox if the drop-down is selected?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

Can anyone help me to change the Fill property of a ComboBox when the ComboBox is selected by the user? Currently, when the drop-down is clicked the values to be selected are transparent across the other values in the gallery. I'd like to set the fill property to white on drop-down so the selectable options are clearly visible. Thank you!

I've tried to use ".IsSelected" and ".Selected" but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have properties like below for Combo box control in Power Apps:

- SelectionColor
- SelectionFill
- SelectionTagColor
- SelectionTagFill
- Fill

You might want to utilize those properties based on your requirements.

Here are some Accessibility guidelines for combo box control

[image]

**Documentation**: [Combo box control in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-combo-box)

---

Anyway, if you want to set color conditionally, you can use formula in this format:

```
If(
    IsBlankOrError(dropdownControl.Selected),
    RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1), // Some other color as per your requirements
    RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1) // White
)
```

If the value is selected in drop down, it will show the white color else other color you specified.

Comment: Thank you very much Ganesh! The code worked great. I was able to adjust slightly to accommodate the needs of my app. I appreciate your help.